# Chef-vault: Cannot decrypt passwords

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I'm using [chef-vault](https://github.com/Nordstrom/chef-vault) for securely storing password data in Chef Server.

Encrypting passwords works fine, but decrypting does not work.

```bsh
$ knife encrypt create secrets test '{"test":"foo"}' --admins user1 --mode client
$ knife encrypt update secrets test '{"test":"foo"}' --admins user1,user2 --mode client
ERROR: OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: padding check failed
$ knife decrypt secrets test 'test' --mode client
ERROR: OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: padding check failed
```

Any idea, what's going wrong?

Comment: Reference this for the `padding check failed` message. http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2013/09/10/managing-secrets-with-chef-vault/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that we had for us admins always a `user` and a `client`. Chef-vault uses the `user` to encrypt the password, thus I was not able to decrypt it with my `client` certificate (to precise, with the private key of the `user` *user1*, while there was also a `client` *admin1*).

This was answered by Kevin Moser on [GitHub](https://github.com/Nordstrom/chef-vault/issues/43#issuecomment-29635583).